# has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local

Tags: apache

I have a webpage with http loaded content,
and this font page with https:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,700,regular&subset=latin-ext

which I have embeded in the first page.

When I am loading the page, it's displaying the error below:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local.

Is there anything I can do about it on Apache ?

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 15):

With [`CORS-rfc1918`](https://web.dev/cors-rfc1918-feedback/#chrome%27s-plans-to-enable-cors-rfc1918), chrome will be mandating public websites accessing private content use HTTPS.

**FIX**: You can either serve the content behind HTTPS, or else in your browser flags (eg `chrome://flags`) disable `Block insecure private network requests`

> **block-insecure-private-network-requests**:
> With this flag turned on, any requests to a private network resource from an HTTP website will be blocked.

Answer (score 3):

add header  Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That page does not mention Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network. This newer one describes implementation: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/